# Is permutation matrix necessary for solving a system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

We can think of elementary row operations or elementary matrices as

operations that doesn't change the solution of a system of linear equations...

That's fine with me.. anyhow my question is

> "Are permutation matrices or switching rows operation necessary?"

The reason I am asking this is that it seems we can do without them.

If the equations are like

$$y=3, x+2y=2$$

we can switch or we can simply add second equations to the first,

and subtract the first from the second resulting $$x+3y=5, -y=-3.$$

anyhow I am not quite sure that it would apply to more than $2$ equations...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Elementary row operations include addition/ subtraction of rows. In your example you added one row to another, and this is an elementary operation. So can you clarify your question?

Comment: My question is that "is permutation necessary for solving linear system of equations?" It looks like we can do without permutation if we only want to solve linear equations... I thought elementary operations are come from solving linear equations... So let me clarify this, if we focus on solving linear equations, can we do without permutations, only with constant multiplications and addition of multiplication of other rows...